# In XPath is there a way to return the child tree including tags? if yes, how?

Tags: xpath

For example I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I want to query book and return the following text:

```
<title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
<price>29.99</price>
```

Is it possible in XPath? If yes, how do I go about doing that?

Thank you.

Comment: @user559083: With XPath you select nodes and get the result in any kind of represantation data type of the hosting language (you can also build strings but not that kind of serialization you apparently want).

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted elements, and for explanation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XPath expression can select the nodes you want, but the serialization is up to the programming language (such as XSLT, C#, PHP, Java) that hosts XPath and its API (such as DOM objects and methods).

**This XPath expression**:

```
/*/book[1]/*
```

**selects exactly the wanted nodes**:

```
<title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
<price>29.99</price>
```

The XPath expression above, in plain English, means:

*Select all elements that are children of the first (in document order) `book` element that is a child of the top element (regardless what is its name) of the XML document*.

Comment: let me get this straight, so could use /*/book[1]/* to get the nodes i wanted then all I need to do is rebuild the nodes to get the output i wanted. correct?

Comment: @user559083: Yes, but the correct term is *serialize*, not "rebuild", The nodes as objects are already "built". Producing from an object just a string that records all its data is called serialization -- because this process converts a 2-dimentional object into 1-dimensional string.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the child nodes of the first book, you can do this:

```
//book[1]/*
```

Or a bit more explicit:

```
/bookstore/book[1]/*
```

Comment: +1 Right answer, but remember that the default axe is the `child` axe and it's better not to use a starting `//` operator when the schema is known. So, `/bookstore/book[1]/*` would be the "standar" expression.

Comment: @Alejandro: Ah, thanks for the tip about the axis.  I didn't realize it wasn't needed.